# Preserve correct ancestry in git rebase with child branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a repo that looks somewhat like this:

```
*-*-*-*-master
   \-*-*-*-feature1
          \-*-*-feature1-experiment
```

Where `feature1-experiment` contains an experimental feature built on top of what's already been built in `feature1`, or it might be just a different approach to the problem. Both `feature1` and `feature1-experiment` are local branches.

Now, other people in my have pushed changes to `master` and I'll rebase `feature1` to get those changes. Now `feature1-experiment` is "out of sync", since the commits in `feature1` are reapplied after rebasing, leaving it pointing to the old commits.

In my head, this is what it looks like:

```
*-*-*-*-master
  |    \-*-*-*-rebased_feature1
  |
   \-*-*-*-old_feature1
          \-*-*feature1-experiment
```

Whereas what I wanted was closer to:

```
*-*-*-*-master
       \-*-*-*-rebased_feature1
              \-rebased_feature1-experiment
```

Is there a way to make it so that when I rebase a branch, all branches created from it get the same operations applied to them? If not, what's the best way to do it manually?

Comment: Have you tried rebasing feature1_experinent on rebased_feature1? Just a thought, I expect it to not work,but git has surprised me before.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do this manually. You might also consider incorporating feature1-experiment into feature1. Long-lived branches can be a pain to deal with in terms of process and the eventual merge.

After rebasing feature1, run

```
git rebase feature1 feature1-experiment
```

The command above is condensed way of executing

```
git checkout feature1-experiment
git rebase feature1
```